# TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony

I try to get a new list for each country select, in symfony, with jquery.
For this i use ajax, but i have this error :

```
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a
```

My jquery :

```
$('.country').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ path('ajax') }}?country_id=" + val,
            success: function(data) {
                $('.extension').html('');
                $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                    $('.extension').append('<option value="' + v + '">' + k + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

My path ajax call my function ajax in controller :

```
public function ajaxAction(Request $request) {
    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }

    // Get extension ID
    $numCountry = $request->query->get('country_id');

    $result = array();

    $extensions  = $this->get('extension')->getExtensionByCountry($numCountry, array('name' => 'asc'));
    foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
        //$result[$extension->getName()] = $extension->getId();
        $result['test'] = 1;
    }

    return new JsonResponse($result);
}
```

Comment: How look your data ?

Comment: you are iterating a string there.. use $.parseJSON(data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over a string, that is causing this error.Try using `$.parseJSON(data)`

```
success: function(data) {
       $('.extension').html('');
       data = $.parseJSON(data);
       $.each(data, function(k, v) {
             $('.extension').append('<option value="' + v + '">' + k + '</option>');
        });
}
```

Read more [$.parseJson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

Comment: Thnaks for your answer i have test with  data = $.parseJSON(data); bit i have now this error : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: put console.log(data) and tell me what you've received, please.

Comment: console.log(data) return the code of my page ... I don't understand why that get this

Comment: It is hitting your method on `ajax` request ?

Comment: I don't think, for test i write in my fonction 'die;' and nothing change, so he don't hit my function ?

Comment: It seems the problem is here: `url: "{{ path('ajax') }}?country_id=" + val,`.

Comment: Probably you want `url: "{{ path('ajaxAction') }}?country_id=" + val,` .Must go to `ajaxAction` function

Comment: url: "{{ path('ajax') }}?country_id=" + val, call in routing.yml : 
ajax:
     path:     /
     defaults: { _controller: TestBundle:FicheExtension:ajax}

who call my function ajax in my controller

Comment: Try to return a message in `new JsonResponse` and see if works.

Comment: New jsonResponse in my controller ? I do this but that change nothing.
In my routing.yml, i tried to change 'ajax" by a fail function, and nothing change too, so my url don't hit my path... and i don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your data is an array ? this normaly happen when you use "each" on a non array element.

I would like to suggest you few more things :

- use FOS js routing : http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html . It will be better for you to put you ajax in js files
- you shoudln't name you method 'ajax' but instead use a clearer name

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes i get a list of extension, so i need an array.
And i have test without array, juste with one fake value : $result['test'] = 1; but i have the same error :/
For now i have call my path 'ajax' just for test, i will change that :)